# TFS Command line result store to local variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, tfs

I am trying to find difference between two folders by using TFS Command line arguments. TFS Command line arguments working fine. but now wants to get only difference result from summary.

**TFS COMMAND :**

```
tf folderdiff serverpath Localpath /recursive /login:username,password /noprompt
```

Above Command works fine gives me below result.

=============================================================================
    Show Items That Have Different Contents    =============================================================================

```
  Show difference file details
```

=============================================================================
 Summary: 9 folders, 34 files, 0 source, 17 target, 1 different, 0 with errors    =============================================================================

Now How i could store  only **"1 different"** inside my local variable in batch file so that i could increase build number.

Any pointers for this?

Answer (score 0):

Got Solution using following commands in batch file

Store result in any new txt file and execute following commands

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /L "different" "C:tmp.txt " ') do set "batToolDir=%%a"
echo "%batToolDir%"

@echo off & setlocal
for /f "tokens=10" %%a in ("%batToolDir%") do  echo  %%a set "finalresult=%%a"
echo "%finalresult%"

Comment: The view switch may help a little bit.